# the upload path does not appear to be valid in image upload code

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever im run this code,its shows me everytime t**he upload path does not appear to be valid** in image upload code.

im new in codeigniter.
Pls Help for this issue.
Thanks.

```
function uploadImage($name,$folder)
    {
        $response = array();

      //  $config['upload_path'] = base_url() . "uploads/demo/image/".$folder."/";
        $config['upload_path'] = base_url() . "./image/".$folder."/";

        $config["allowed_types"] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config["encrypt_name"] = true;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload($name))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $config3 = array(
                'source_image' =>$data['full_path'],
                'new_image' => './image/'.$folder.'/thumb/',
                'maintain_ratio' => true,
                'width' => 150,
                'height' => 100
            );
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config3);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $name = $data['file_name'];

            $response['flag'] = "true";
            $response['name'] = $name;

        }
        else
        {
            $response['flag'] = "false";
            $response['name'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        print_r($response);
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Learn the difference between a URL, and a file system path. `base_url()` returns the former. You can not move a file “to a URL”, you need to use an actual file system path.

Answer (score 0):

add this in config/config.php file

```
$config['base_path']    = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../');
define('BASE_PATH',$config['base_path']);
```

after that
Use this

```
$config['upload_path'] = BASE_PATH . "/image/".$folder."/"; //C:\wamp\www\ , absolute path
```

instead of this

```
$config['upload_path'] = base_url() . "/image/".$folder."/";//http://localhost/ ,relative path
```

Comment: sorry but, do not understood properly.

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki, Did you test with the above solution, So first you need to read the $config['upload_path'] description in [https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html] documentation

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in:

> $config['upload_path'] = base_url() . "./image/".$folder."/";

it should be `$config['upload_path'] = base_url("image/$folder/");`

Further should be noted, that the error could also appear, when you are on a shared server and need to address a relative path (your home directory at the server, you find it at your cPanel main page).

I found below approach resolving the upload path for both, my localhost and my shared server:

```
$url = "./image/$folder/";  // LOCALHOST
$cur_url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //=='www.mydomain.com')

if (strpos($cur_url, 'mydomain.com') !== false) {
  // PRODUCTION
  $url = "/home/username/public_html/mydomain.com/image/$folder/";
}

$config['upload_path'] = $url;
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

function uploadImage($name,$folder)
    {
        $response = array();

```
  //  $config['upload_path'] = base_url() . "uploads/demo/image/".$folder."/";
    $config['upload_path'] = base_url() . "./image/".$folder."/";

    $config["allowed_types"] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config["encrypt_name"] = true;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload($name))
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $config3 = array(
            'source_image' =>$data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => './image/'.$folder.'/thumb/',
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 100
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config3);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $name = $data['file_name'];

        $response['flag'] = "true";
        $response['name'] = $name;

    }
    else
    {
        $response['flag'] = "false";
        $response['name'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    print_r($response);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: must to upload 1

function uploadImage($name,$folder) { $response = array();